# Julia DataFrames.jl - filter data with NA's (NAException)

Tags: julia

I am not sure how to handle `NA` within Julia DataFrames.

For example with the following DataFrame:

```
> import DataFrames
> a = DataFrames.@data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
> b = DataFrames.@data([3, 4, 5, 6, NA]);
> ndf = DataFrames.DataFrame(a=a, b=b)
```

I can successfully execute the following operation on column `:a`

```
> ndf[ndf[:a] .== 4, :]
```

but if I try the same operation on `:b` I get an error `NAException("cannot index an array with a DataArray containing NA values")`.

```
> ndf[ndf[:b] .== 4, :]

NAException("cannot index an array with a DataArray containing NA values")
while loading In[108], in expression starting on line 1

in to_index at /Users/abisen/.julia/v0.3/DataArrays/src/indexing.jl:85
in getindex at /Users/abisen/.julia/v0.3/DataArrays/src/indexing.jl:210
in getindex at /Users/abisen/.julia/v0.3/DataFrames/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:268
```

Which is because of the presence of NA value.

My question is how should DataFrames with `NA` should typically be handled? I can understand that `>` or `<` operation against `NA` would be `undefined` but `==` should work (no?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's your desired behavior here?  If you want to do selections like this you can make the condition (not a NAN) AND (equal to 4).  If the first test fails then the second one never happens.

```
using DataFrames
a = @data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
b = @data([3, 4, 5, 6, NA]);
ndf = DataFrame(a=a, b=b)
ndf[(!isna(ndf[:b]))&(ndf[:b].==4),:]
```

In some cases you might just want to drop all rows with NAs in certain columns

```
ndf = ndf[!isna(ndf[:b]),:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859094/indexing-julias-dataarrays-with-included-na-values) question I asked before, you can change this NA behavior directly in the modules sourcecode if you want. In the file `indexing.jl` there is a function named `Base.to_index(A::DataArray)` beginning at line 75, where you can alter the code to set NA's in the boolean array to `false`. For example you can do the following:

```
# Indexing with NA throws an error
function Base.to_index(A::DataArray)
    A[A.na] = false
    any(A.na) && throw(NAException("cannot index an array with a DataArray containing NA values"))
    Base.to_index(A.data)
end
```

Ignoring NA's with `isna()` will cause a less readable sourcecode and in big formulas, a performance loss:

```
@timeit ndf[(!isna(ndf[:b])) & (ndf[:b] .== 4),:]  #3.68 µs per loop
@timeit ndf[ndf[:b] .== 4, :]  #2.32 µs per loop

## 71x179 2D Array
@timeit dm[(!isna(dm)) & (dm .< 3)] = 1  #14.55 µs per loop  
@timeit dm[dm .< 3] = 1  #754.79 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you want to treat NA as separate instances, i.e. assume that  that everything that is NA is "equal" and everything else is different.

If this is the behaviour you want, current DataFrames API doesn't help you much, as both `(NA == NA)` and `(NA == 1)` returns `NA` instead of their expected boolean results.

This makes extremely tedious DataFrame filters using loops:

`function filter(df,c)
    for r in eachrow(df)
        if (isna(c) && isna(r:[c])) || ( !isna(r[:c]) && r[:c] == c   )
        ...`

and breaks select-like functionalities in `DataFramesMeta.jl` and `Query.jl` when `NA` values are present or requested for..

One workaround is to use `isequal(a,b)` in place of `a==b`

```
test = @where(df, isequal.(:a,"cc"), isequal.(:b,NA) ) #from DataFramesMeta.jl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the new syntax in Julia is to use ismissing:

```
# drop NAs
df = DataFrame(col=[0,1,1,missing,0,1])
df = df[.!ismissing.(df[:col]),:]
```